# ./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I have integrated Mapbox GL JS (Version: 1.8.0) in a React (Version: 16.12.0) and it is working fine. But when I am trying run the build command it throws me the below error:

`./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 staging: `env-cmd .env.staging npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 staging script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Can anybody tell me why react build command throwing the error whereas npm start command not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jonas, thanks for the reply.

I have fixed it by the following two steps:

By removing mapbox-gl.css imports from the jsx page
And add the following line in the index.html page

```
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when building with react-scripts@1.1.0. I upgraded to latest (v3.4.0) which fixed the issue for me.

```
npm install --save react-scripts@latest
```

or

```
yarn add react-scripts@latest
```